# Best java library for creating, parsing and querying XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath

I am creating a system which will store c++ code in an xml file so i need to be able to create the xml file from either a string or array of strings and then need to parse and query it at a later moment in the program. What is the best library to do this with ive been looking around at Xpath for querying and simple for creating the document although there doesnt seem to be much helpful documentation on it.
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use VTD-XML, works good with XML and much faster. Deals good with XPATH. I am already been to it. for more info please visit to http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/